# Filter rows by sum/average of their elements

Tags: r, dataframe

In a R script I have a DataFrame in the format:

```
 V1           V2           V3           V4
1  HIAT1 3.917271e-05 4.278916e-05 3.793761e-05
2  SASS6 2.008972e-06 1.890391e-06 2.168946e-06
3 TRMT13 4.397712e-06 4.724036e-06 4.009512e-06
```

Where the first column is a String name and the following are numeric values. 
The total number of values is not known a priori, but depends on the dataset provided as input to the script.

I want to extract only the rows for which the sum(or average) of elements from the second to the last is greater than a certain threshold.

How to do that in R-style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `rowSums/rowMeans` of the numeric columns, get a logical vector using `>` and subset the rows.

```
 thresh <- 0.0001
 df1[rowSums(df1[,-1])> thresh,]
```